# Can Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0) be null?

Tags: android, localization

In my app I need the global system locale and I'm currently taking it as follows

```
      public static Locale getSystemLocale() {
        Locale locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        try {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            locale = Locale.getDefault();
        }

        } else {
           locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
        return locale;
      }
```

But I am wondering is this `try catch` block is really necessary, can `getLocales()` either return null or return an empty array ? Thanks

Comment: which is your minsdk version. I mean which API level using

Comment: @ShaluTD my min target version is API 21, I updated the snippet to show the full code that I'm currently using

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, you don't need to surround that code with a try catch block.

**Because** it doesn't throw exceptions (in the normal scenarios). Fortunately, Android studio warns you to surround the code that could potentially throw exceptions in the first place so you don't have to worry. :)

For example if you are trying to convert a string to number you are only expecting numbers to be present in the string if the string contains anything else except numbers the process of converting string to number can throw and exception. So you should surround such code with `try catch` block.